# MySQL: Computed Column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm just started using SQL and ran into a problem.

In my database, I presently have two tables, Cinemas and Theatres. 
I'm trying to create a column "# of Theatres# in the Cinemas table that counts the number of Theatres in the Theatres table with the same CinemaID (foreign key) as a Cinema in the Cinemas table. I got it to work as an SQL query:

```
SELECT cinemas.CinemaID,Town,COUNT(*) AS '# of Theatres'
FROM cinemax.cinemas,cinemax.theatres
WHERE cinemas.CinemaID=theatres.CinemaID
GROUP BY cinemas.CinemaID;
```

But wanted to know if it's possible to create a column in the Cinemas table, that automatically performs the above query and inserts the value into each row.

It is going to be a very small database so speed isn't really an issue, I just want to learn how to make such a computed column (if even possible).

Comment: Have you tried to use triggers? Check this post out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222044/column-calculated-from-another-column. Hope it helps :)

Comment: just use a mysql view man!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is possible.  but you should not do it.

that is called denormalization - and is usually not a good idea at all.

sometimes however, you might absolutely need to denormalize something for some odd reason (your example is nowhere near a good reason).  in these cases, you need to add trigger code to automatically manage the values whenever anything changes in the system that would affect the results.

Answer (score 12):

A computed column normally means a value you can calculate per row.  MySQL does not support that, but SQL Server does.  For example, to store the sum of two columns permanently:

```
create table Table1 (a int, b int, c as a+b persisted)
```

However, you're looking to store an aggregate, that is, a value for a group of rows.  MySQL and SQL Server don't support materialized views with an aggregate, but Oracle does:

```
create table Table1 (a int, b int);

create materialized view View1 as
select  a
,       count(*) as Cnt
from    Table1
group by
    a;
```

With MySQL however, the closest you can do is a cronjob that periodically populates a table:

```
truncate table Table1Summary;
insert Table1Summary (a, Cnt) select a, count(*) from Table1;
```

You can query the table like a materialized view; it will be as fast, but not guaranteed to be up to date.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I guess sticking with a query makes more sense then since it's always up to date.

Comment: MySQL 5.7 supports generated columns, where an expression which can be stored or virtual, and a virtual generated column can be indexed where the index stores the value. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html

Answer (score 2):

In mysql you if you want an actual column you would

- create it as any column
- make sure it is consistent by creating a trigger on theatre table that will update the column ever time a row is added or deleted

Answer (score 2):

MySql does support generated columns in 5.7

Comment: Relevant link to the docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html

Comment: I am trying to use the auto-generated columns functionality via MySQL while trying to interact with the db using JDBC.

-The auto-generated cell which should actually display the result as per the framed query, that cell is editable and not blocked for auto-generation, and erroring out.

Let me know please what changes do i need to my code for that row to auto populate.

Also, since auto-generation feature got introduced in Mysql 5.7, but I am using 5.1 ver connector/driver. Could that be a problem??