# mysql alter table with value base on other field

Tags: mysql, database-design, alter

i have dateOfbirth field in my table and i need to add new field age and it is base on dateOfBirth field w/c is i need to compute as their age?
is it possible to alter the table and set the value of the field base on other field?

Comment: column age is not recommended to be added because you will always update it every year right? so better leave it out.

Comment: opo/yes kuya john but i need to make their age computed for the use of sphinx database indexing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ALTER` table to add a new column. And then use `UPDATE` to update that column based on your dateOfBirth field.

Comment: so it is not possible to alter with value?

Comment: judged by the syntax of alter http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html - no

Comment: yes. it's value is stale unless u run the update stmt. and why should the database store the age as the age is dependent merely on birthdate and now() so it is error prone. the age should be returned instantaneously from a select stmt or a view. got it ?

Comment: let's say u run the update stmt. and tomorrow is his birthday. how often are u running the update stmt. your code breaks. there should be no column saying what their age is except for a computed column in a view or a direct select stmt

Comment: otherwise what are u doing, constantly running cron jobs to update ages ... nuts

Comment: no because the age is stored. then no more updates. you have an age in the row saying the guy is 13 then three years go by and no more update. then the next select stmt says he is 13 but he is 16.

Comment: you dont store the age. u store the birthdate. you return the age instantaneously via a select or a view pretty simple.

Comment: let's say u are writing an app for a bank. would u save the checking account balance in the user record? balance =1000. you withdraw 100. balance =1000. withdraw 100. balance =1000. no your balance is a computed column based on entries in transactions of deposits and withdrawals. so balance is a computed field. so is age. it is based on birthdate and now(). you dont store computed values (age,balance). you display them dynamically at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a COMPUTED column that will be updated automatically when dateOfBirth is updated. Unfortunately, [MySQL does not support computed columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422729/mysql-computed-column), so your choices are:

- Create a view as described above
- Create a normal age column and maintain its values by adding a trigger to original table that would constantly recompute values in age column when values in dateOfBirth column change
- Compute age when you query data by adding additional column to your query
- (best case because it reduces the load on the database) Compute age in the application