# Declare a table has a column that is the product of two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

Table Product

```
id  name   price   quantity   total

1     food    50      1         50
2     drink   20      2         40
3     dress   100     3         300
```

How do I declare a table that has a column that is the product of two columns?

I have this code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders] (
    [Id]          INT        IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ProductName] NCHAR (70) NULL,
    [Price]       INT        NULL,
    [Quantity]    INT        NULL,
    [Total] INT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Do you really want a field to store the `total` -- perhaps that would be more appropriate to calculate in your sql or in a `view`?  If you do want a `computed column`, declare it like such: `[Total] INT AS (Price * Quantity)`

Comment: `[Total] INT AS (Price * Quantity),` gives me error in the use of AS in T-SQL in C#

Comment: Looks like it's not supported: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422729/mysql-computed-column

Comment: Maybe you want a separate table for storing the tables of multiplication?

Comment: No, i have in this table. And dont work this code `ALTER TABLE [Orders] ADD TOT INT AS Price * Quantity;`    :(

Comment: Why do this?  Just build it into your query/application

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want a [`VIEW`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html).

Their example is exactly what you're describing

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE t (qty INT, price INT);
mysql> INSERT INTO t VALUES(3, 50);
mysql> CREATE VIEW v AS SELECT qty, price, qty*price AS value FROM t;
mysql> SELECT * FROM v;
+------+-------+-------+
| qty  | price | value |
+------+-------+-------+
|    3 |    50 |   150 |
+------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this mate:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_product_total;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER trg_product_total AFTER INSERT ON product
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET @price = NULL, @quantity = NULL;  

  SELECT price INTO @price FROM product
  WHERE id = NEW.id;  

  SELECT quantity INTO @quantity
  WHERE id = NEW.id;  

  UPDATE product SET total = @price * @quantity
  WHERE id = NEW.id;
END;
```

You can use this kind of approach if you don't really want to process the product.total before inserting it into the DB.

The Trigger will execute each time a new record is added into the table, wherein the expected insert for the total column is either 'NULL' or '0' depending on your default value.

But I think it would be better if you calculate it before the insert.

The flow would be like:

```
Application side
1. get price and quantity for the product
2. calculate for the total
3. insert values into the query
4. execute query
```

In case you want to learn more about MySQL Trigger: [*Link*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html)
Also, PHP Transaction: [*Link*](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php)