# Fetch timestamps as integers in MySQL by default

Tags: mysql, timestamp

How do you set in MySQL the timestamp type column to be returned as integer by default?

To specify:

I know that I can query

```
select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp_column) from table ...,
```

but when I query

```
select * from table ...
```

How can I force `timestamp_column` to be returned as `int`, and not as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii:ss`, in every query like the previous one?

Is there a query like `set names utf8` that I can execute to make the described behaviour default?

Comment: if the datatype is `timestamp` then doing just `select col1,col2...` should return the timestamp col value as `YYYY-MM-DD H:i:s`

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the solution. I don't want it as YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii:ss but by default as **integer**

Comment: Then you are left with no choice but to use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` as far as I know.

Comment: If this is so (well I have been reading the MySQL documentation a lot for this), as well as I believe too, I think it is a shortcoming in MySQL.

Comment: No that’s not a shortcoming , the datetime, timestamp values are stored in the proper format in the DB. When you do queries with date its easy to use different functionality. However while selecting and getting data as integer value is of certain requirement and for this you have a function `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: For the shortcoming, I meant only that default return type for timestamp cannot be set. Naturally, the benefits of having timestamp type column are evident.

Comment: In SQL server, a generated or computed column solves this problem, but not in MYSQL.  Look here on how to use triggers as a work around: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422729/mysql-computed-column