# MySQL Calculate Derived Attribute

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a derived attribute `Fine` in a MySQL table, whose value is

```
(CurrentDate - DueDate) * 0.5
```

`CurrentDate` and `DueDate` are stored in the table in the `Date` format.

How can I specify this formula for `Fine` attribute in my table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Loan (
         loanID    INT UNSIGNED  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
         BorrowDate  DATE       DEFAULT NULL,
         ReturnDate         DATE       DEFAULT NULL,
         DueDate         DATE       DEFAULT NULL,
--- Fine... What do I write for Fine here-------
         userID    INT UNSIGNED  NOT NULL,           
         itemID    INT UNSIGNED  NOT NULL,      
         PRIMARY KEY  (loanID) ,
         FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES LibraryUser (userID),
         FOREIGN KEY (itemID) REFERENCES Items (itemID)
       );
```

Comment: SQL is the language, which varies with different database products. Which RDBMS are you using? SQL Server/MySQL/Oracle etc.

Comment: How you want to get `Fine` in minutes in hours, ...?

Comment: @Bridge-  I am using MySQL

Comment: @HamletHakobyan- I want fine in days... Fine is number of days multiplied by 0.5

Comment: This question is lacking a lot of information. Please show some code.

Comment: Couldn't you use a view ?

Comment: @njk- See Edit..Code included

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus- Please include code for whatever you are suggesting

Comment: Don't make a column at all. Calculate the value in whatever SELECT query you write.

Comment: The fine value probably needs to be `GREATEST(0, (CurrentDate-DueDate)*0.5)` to avoid the library owing people money if they return the book before the due date.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler- Please provide the proper MySQL syntax for the same.

Comment: @user1628340: Errm...what was wrong with the syntax of `GREATEST(0, (CurrentData-DueDate)*0.5)` — the [Fine Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) says that should work in MySQL 5.0 or later.

Answer (score 5):

You can't have a computed column "as is" in mysql.

Three solutions :

**First** : use triggers

see for example [column calculated from another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222044/column-calculated-from-another-column)

**Second** : create a view (Fine will exist only in your view, not in your main table).

view can contain computed columns without any problem.

```
CREATE VIEW v_computedLoan AS
SELECT
loanID, 
BorrowDate, 
ReturnDate, 
CurrentDate,
--etc
(CurrentDate-DueDate)*0.5 as Fine
FROM Loan
```

**Third** : keep calculation out of your db. Use this in your queries only.

EDIT : if CurrentDate is really the same as CURRENT_DATE() function (and then should vary), solution with triggers won't work, and CurrentDate shouldn't be stored in any table (but you can still use it in a view).

Comment: +1 but I don't think a trigger would work... He needs to update that column every day regardless of any table changes.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Hmmm, in fact CurrentDate is stored in the table, so it might work.

Comment: You should not store the current date in the table.  Likewise, any 'age' column is inherently dubious in a stored table.  'Age on Relevant Date' is legitimate (though unnecessary because calculable), but 'current age' is not a good attribute (because, given enough people in the database, it changes for some of the people every day).  The question does mention 'current date is stored in the table', but I think that's a typo; it isn't shown and shouldn't be stored.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler well, I just saw that in the question, a CurrentDate column exists in the table. But... we don't know what's inside ! (If it's "today", of course, it's a very bad idea).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler in fact, you seem to be right (Fine calculation seems to indicate that). Hmmm, or maybe there's a confusion between returnDate (which is present in question's table sample) and CurrentDate (which is not)