# make new column with math function in table

Tags: mysql, function

```
id    data1        data2       
1      10          15           
2      10          20
```

I have this table, and I want to add new column (point) in this table.

```
id     data1      data2        point
1      100         105           5
2      100         200          100
```

I'd like to add this point value by calculating this formula as follows:

```
point = (data2 - data1)/data1 * 100
```

How can I add this value into point column?

Please let me know. 
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Column calculated from another column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222044/column-calculated-from-another-column)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use a VIEW

```
CREATE VIEW vw_Table1 AS
SELECT id, data1, data2, (data2 - data1)/data1 * 100 point
  FROM table1
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7216c/1)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use a trigger to keep it updated as @Yogendra Singh said, but if its a one-time thing then you can do it in a single UPDATE statement:

```
ALTER TABLE data ADD COLUMN point integer;
UPDATE data SET point = (data2 - data1)/data1 * 100;
```

The trigger function would look like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_point BEFORE INSERT ON data
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.point = (data2 - data1)/data1 * 100;
  END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a `after insert/update` trigger to update the point column after inserting/updating the values in the data1 and data2 columns.

You may want to refer [Creating Triggers in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en///create-trigger.html) for more details.