# "Syntax error at or near SET" on trigger create

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables (stock and productsLot) and I need a trigger that calculates the total quantity of a product(in stock table) by summing the lot quantities(from productsLot).

I don't know much about triggers but my problem is similar to this one [Calculate column value from another column in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157972/calculate-column-value-from-another-column-in-another-table). Here's my case.

```
CREATE TABLE Stock (productId INTEGER,totalQuantity INTEGER, price NUMERIC(30,2))
PRIMARY KEY (productId); 

CREATE TABLE productsLot (productId INTEGER CONSTRAINT fk_stock_productsLot REFERENCES ON Stock(productId) , lotNumber VARCHAR, lotQuantity INTEGER, expirationDate DATE, PRIMARY KEY (productId, lotNumber)); 

CREATE TRIGGER update_quantity_stock
BEFORE INSERT ON  stock SET NEW.totalQuantity = 
  (
    SELECT sum(lotQuantity)
      FROM productsLot
     WHERE productId = NEW.productId
     LIMIT 1
  );
```

I'm getting this error:

> syntax error at or near "SET"

Comment: The question you linked is for MySQL triggers. In Postgres, you need to write a trigger procedure. There are examples in the docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-EXAMPLE

Comment: Got it ! Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

Quite a foolish question apparently but I got it thanks to Nick. 
Here's the solution

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_quantity_stock()
    RETURNS trigger AS
  $$
  BEGIN
           UPDATE stock SET totalQuantity = (select sum(lotQuantity)
        FROM productsLot
       WHERE productsLot.productId=stock.productId);

      RETURN NEW;
  END;
  $$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

-- trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_quantity_stock_trigger
   AFTER INSERT
   ON productsLot
   FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_quantity_stock();
```