# Creating a SQL table, how can I convert a BIT entry to text YES or NO?

Tags: mysql, sql

Very new to SQL and trying to set up a users table, I have a check box for financial aid that outputs a BIT 0 or 1, ideally what I would like to do is convert this value to a YES or NO depending on the value. Right now I'm not entirely sure how to do this, I've tried adding

```
SELECT CASE `financial_aid`
         WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes' 
         WHEN 0 THEN 'No' 
       END As `financial_aid`
FROM `users`;
```

Currently this doesn't solve my problem, can anyone advise how I can fix this?

**SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `User_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `player_name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `dob` date NOT NULL,
  `parent_name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `parent_email` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `parent_phone` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `experience` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `financial_aid` bit NOT NULL,
  `registration_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`User_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10;

SELECT CASE `financial_aid`
          WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes'
          WHEN 0 THEN 'No' 
       END As `financial_aid` 
FROM `users`;
```

Comment: `Currently this doesn't solve my problem` - it gives an error?

Comment: hey, currently it just registers as either 00000001 or 00000000 in my database instead of Yes or No

Comment: Your query works fine : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4ae2/2

Comment: Please elaborate more on why this doesn't solve your problem.  Are you actually asking for a statement that will change the contents of the table?

Comment: Hey, yeah I would like my financial_aid column to display Yes or No, at the moment I just see the following: http://d.pr/i/uGyO

Comment: If you want this persisted in the table, then you'll probably need a  new column and a synchronizing [trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222044/column-calculated-from-another-column) (MySql doesn't support Computed columns). Otherwise, just modify the query or presentation tier (e.g. screen) so that it maps it as you've done with the `case ... when`

Answer (score 2):

Try `IF(true, x, y)` function ...

```
SELECT IF(`financial_aid`, 'Yes', 'No') As `financial_aid` FROM `users`;
```

Or simply

```
SELECT case `financial_aid`
         WHEN TRUE 'Yes'
         ELSE 'No' END
        As `financial_aid`
FROM `users`;
```