# Need an update statement that multiplies two column values from diffrent table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have 2 tables **customer and milk** as shown below

**customers**

```
customers (cid, name,  price);
```

**milk**

```
milk (mid, customer_id, milk_letters, mprice)
```

I need an update query to multiply `price`, `milk_letters` and store in `mprice where customer_id = cid`

This is my insert statement that is wrong, I need to change it to update statement.

```
$cid = $_POST['cid'];
$milk_letters = $_POST['milk_letters'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO milk (customer_id, milk_letters, milk_date)
        VALUES ('$cid','$milk_letters', NOW())";
dbQuery($sql);  
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO milk SELECT SUM(price * milk_letters) as mprice FROM customers , milk WHERE customers.cid = '$cid' and milk.customer_id = '$cid'";
    $result2 = dbQuery($sql2);
```

Comment: take a look at this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222044/column-calculated-from-another-column

Comment: If you want to modify an existing row, you use `UPDATE`, not `INSERT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in one query rather than 2

```
INSERT INTO milk (customer_id, milk_letters, milk_date, mprice)
SELECT {$cid}, {$milk_letters}, NOW(), customers.price * {$milk_letters}
FROM customers
WHERE customers.cid = {$cid}
```

Comment: okay next thing i want to do is i want to add all mprice of particular customer means will add one more column total in customers and add mprice where cusoter_id = cid

Comment: Something like UPDATE customers SET total = (SELECT SUM(mprice) FROM milk WHERE milk.cid = customers.cid) - although from a programming point of view its better to calculate this value rather than store it - you could create a view CREATE VIEW customertotals AS SELECT customer.cid, milk.milk_letters * customers.price AS milktotal GROUP BY customer.cid - and then just use SELECT cid, milktotal FROM customertotals