# Is it possible to add an column that has the average value from the other columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm wondering if it is possible to have a column that has the AVG value of the other columns of the same table.

For example:

```
Columns:   ID 125Hz 250Hz 500Hz 750Hz 1000Hz 1500Hz 2000Hz 3000Hz 4000Hz 6000Hz 8000Hz AVG
Values:    1  92    82     63    83    32     43     54     56     54     34      54    50
```

Can it calculate the average of all the other columns and put the average value automatically on the AVG column? I am using PHPMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

It's my understanding that MySQL doesn't have computed columns.  Somebody correct me if I am wrong.

Therefore, you essentially need this statement.

```
UPDATE [table_name] SET [AVG] = (125Hz + 250Hz + 500Hz + 750Hz + 1000Hz + 1500Hz + 2000Hz + 3000Hz + 4000Hz + 6000Hz + 8000Hz ) / 11;
```

For each row, add up the column values and divide by 11 because there are 11 such columns.  It's not the most elagent because you need to hard-code 11, but it's better than nothing.

You could put this into a trigger on the table so it updates each row when it changes.  I think that will get you what you need.

A similar question and answer was asked and the trigger there may be helpful for you: [Column calculated from another column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222044/column-calculated-from-another-column)

Comment: This didnt work as a trigger. Do you know how the code would look be fit as a trigger?

Comment: I haven't worked with MySQL enough to show how to do it.  You say it didn't work.  What was the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can't put this in your original table but you can create a view to accomplish this:

```
CREATE VIEW column_avg AS
SELECT (125Hz + 250Hz)/2 AS total_avg
FROM table_name;
```

Just list all of the columns in the addition part and divide by the number of columns.

Comment: This is the average of the averages of the averages - is that what you meant?

Comment: I thought that's what they meant but seems I was incorrect, updated