# Put a SELECT into my column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

My table has 4 columns. I want the last column to be a SUM of the previous 3 columns.

I can use a select command to get the result I want:

SELECT strength + agility + defense AS StatSum
FROM userstats

How do I do this?

EDIT: I am looking how to place the SELECT command in the column so that column 4 will display the sum of each row.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Column calculated from another column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222044/column-calculated-from-another-column)

Answer (score 0):

Try soemthing like:

```
 SELECT strength, agility, defense, (strength + agility + defense) AS StatSum 
 FROM userstats
```

Comment: The SELECT command works. I was asking how to place the select command in a column. So the command runs works out the total stats for each row

Comment: No that wont be possible.

Comment: You could do it with your application layer

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not support calculated values for a column.

The only thing you could do is to use a [view](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html)