# Computed Column in Mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to add a computeed column.

```
alter table datatest add column amount2 double  as (amount*rate)
```

but I got error while executing this

Comment: Welcome to SO :-)
Please look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Column calculated from another column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222044/column-calculated-from-another-column)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't support computed columns prior to MySQL 5.7.  The more recent versions do now support computed columns.

You can use a view instead:

```
create view v_datatest as
    select t.*, (amount * rate) as amount2
    from datatest;
```

Notes:

- In databases that do support computed columns, the type is not part of the column definition.  It is derived from the expression (you can use `cast()`/`convert()` to convert to a particular type).
- It is a bad idea to store monetary amounts using floating point representations.  You should be using `decimal`/`numeric` instead.
- If you don't want to use a view, you can add a column to the table (along with the type) and use a trigger to maintain the value.

Comment: I wounder why someone marks answer as usefulness without telling why, despite the good information and efforts  contained in this answer!!!!