# How to get sum of multiple count and price sqlite - android

Tags: android, sqlite

I created a table like this :

```
id   price   count    product_id

1    100      1           1
2    120      3           3
...
```

now I would like to get sum of all multiple `count` and `price` .

for this example :

(100 * 1) + (120 * 3) = 460

what I want is : `460`

is it possible to use only the sql ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I have same issue. you can try using this Query

```
Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(count * price) FROM myTable", null);
if(cur.moveToFirst())
{
    return cur.getInt(0);
}
```

This was work for me.

Answer (score -1):

If you use the total often, you can store the result of the multiplication in a [calculated column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5222044/1440565). Then you only need to sum that column.