# SQL column name based on primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

ID column set to primary key, auto increment.

I want to have a second column Project number, is it possible to set something like this in SQL ? Or how should I do this ?

ID: 1 projectnumber:Project001

ID: 2 projectnumber:Project002

.

.

.

ID: n projectnumber: Project00n

Comment: You don't even need to have the column, just format this when you pull the data out and when you display it in the application.. All you're doing is duplicating string `Project` and adding a number next to the title - there's very, very little point in wasting space like that.

Comment: Sounds like a calculated column: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222044/column-calculated-from-another-column

Comment: MySQL 5.7 you can use a generated column (GENERATED ALWAYS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do that in 2 ways:

Either using a trigger or do that when retrieving the record from the database:

trigger: after insert

```
CREATE TRIGGER `yourtable_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `yourtable` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE yourtable
     SET projectnumber = CONCAT('project', NEW.id) 
     WHERE id = NEW.id;
END;
```

or
just do that CONCAT thing in your select query or even better in the logic of php. Consider the possibility you want to translate your application. You would store duplicate information as well...

as pointed out below: NEW.id will not work.
So use  LAST_INSERT_ID()  instead:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `yourtable_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `yourtable` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE yourtable
     SET projectnumber = CONCAT('project', LAST_INSERT_ID()) 
     WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END;
```

but still: it would be duplicating content

Comment: In a BEFORE trigger, the NEW value for an AUTO_INCREMENT column is 0, not the sequence number that is generated automatically when the new row actually is inserted.

Comment: "NEW" not work with "AFTER" and "set column_name" not work.