# SQL - Computed Columns / Triggers?

Tags: sql

I have created two tables:

In the first table I want to store a computed result in the 3rd column

```
Table 1

num1|num2|num3
```

I want to have `num3` = `num1+num2`, after every update, insert, delete

My second table is for a percent calculation, something like a wishlist

```
Table 2 

value|stored|left
```

I want to have `left` = `stored/value`, ie. a percentage of the amount stored vs the value of an item.

How can I set these values up to compute on update, insert, delete?

**Original**:

i have created two tabels, in first one i try to store the result in the 3'rd column ex: my tabel structure num1|num2|num3

where num3=num1+num2 ,after every update,insert,delete

second tabel is for a percent calculation, something like a wishlist structure: value,stored,left

where value = the value of the object u wanna buy, ex 1250 stored is the ammount that you saved for your wish left is the percent left to achive your goal

same problem like the first tabel

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: Please tag RDBMS you are using, Also please add sample data in text format. what have you tried so far ?

Comment: idk how i can do that, thats the problem

Comment: @TerchilăMarian I cleaned up your question, please check that the logic is correct.  Also, tag your DBMS as House mentioned.

Comment: you deleted my question...

Comment: @TerchilăMarian I put your original question back in too.  Edit it so it makes sense.

Comment: Why store values you can easily calculate?

Comment: @TerchilăMarian This question still needs the appropriate tag to indicate which DBMS you're using.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Column calculated from another column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222044/column-calculated-from-another-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a `trigger` will help update your table after `insert` or `update` on the table will help `update` column , assuming u have an ID column in the table

```
CREATE TRIGGER Insert_Update ON mytable
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF 
        UPDATE (num3)

    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.Mytable
        SET num3 = i.num1 + i.num2
        FROM inserted i
        INNER JOIN mytable t ON i.MyID = t.MyID
        LEFT JOIN deleted d ON i.MyID = d.MyID
        WHERE d.MyID IS NULL AND i.ColumnB IS NOT NULL -- Row was inserted
            OR d.MyID IS NOT NULL -- Row was updated
    END
END
GO
```

Comment: What is the `if UPDATE(num3)` doing?

Comment: Shouldn't this be `IF UPDATE(num1, num2)` ?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you store the num1 and num2 values in variables before setting num3. Unless you perform an *INSERT* first in the first two columns and then an *UPDATE* on the num3 column.

Sometimes a database isn't set for autocommit, so you'll need to force it and after that reuse the values.

Comment: You probably won't do what you want in one single statement, because the values you'll need aren't on the table yet. Try to insert the first values, and then use a TRIGGER AFTER INSERT to UPDATE the NUM3. Be sure to set the trigger only for "after insert" otherwise you'll get a loop.

BEGIN

DECLARE num1_v  numeric(15,2)
DECLARE num2_v  numeric(15,2)
DECLARE num3_v  numeric(15,2)

SELECT num1_v = NUM1, num2_v = NUM2
FROM inserted (or deleted)
WHERE <PK> = <PK> 

UPDATE <TABLE>
set NUM3 = num1_v + num2_v
WHERE <PK> = <PK>

END