# SQL: I need a column to update its value automatically based on other columns' values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Suppose we have two tables:

- `Employees` (id (pk), salary)
- `Bonus` (id (fk), increase, total)

`bonus.id` is a FK that references the PK 'employees.id'.

I want `total` to be equal to `employees.salary + bonus.increase` by default. I also want the value to be assigned to total whenever salary or bonus are updated.

What sql or pl/sql statements are capable of doing this?

Note: I'm an absolute noob.

Comment: Use Trigger to achieve the same.

Comment: Consider not storing derived data at all. Get them with a view.

Comment: Create `after update` trigger https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48385268/sql-computed-columns-triggers/48385800#48385800

Comment: You could use the triggers to achieve that but that would be a very bad choice. As a matter of fact you probably don't require the total column at all. You could have that column in a view as mentioned by @Thumbquat.

Comment: @Tejash----ORA-00980 I'm looking up triggers right now. I think they will do the trick. I just have never heard of them before. Thanks!

Comment: @Serg I can't use a view. I'm just working on an assignment.

Comment: Thanks! I think I have to use a trigger. I know it's not a good choice and the tables don't really make sense, but I'm only doing this for educational purposes

Comment: This is not an answer. It should be a comment - indeed you are agreeing with posted comments - but obviously you don't have sufficient reputation points to post comments yet. Alas, posting non-answers like this should not be the way to gain points

Comment: You should expand this so that it becomes an answer. How would you solve it with a trigger (provide a working example based on the OP's tables)? Expand on why this is a bad idea. Give an example of how a better solution than a trigger would be implemented.

Comment: In a normal company structure every employee has a salary. However, bonuses are awarded on an ad hoc basis, with no employee guaranteed a bonus, and the bonus awarded might be different each year. Is that your model? When an employee is created do they have a bonus record? Does a new bonus mean a new record or an update to the existing record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answer by @MT0 is perfect.

But if you can not change the structure of the table and need Trigger solution then you need the following two triggers.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_EMPLOYEES AFTER
    UPDATE OF SALARY ON EMPLOYEES
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE BONUS
    SET
        TOTAL = :NEW.SALARY + INCREASE
    WHERE
        ID = :NEW.ID;

END;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_BONUS BEFORE
    INSERT OR UPDATE OF INCREASE ON BONUS
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    LV_TOTAL   BONUS.TOTAL%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT
        SALARY + NVL(:NEW.INCREASE, 0)
    INTO LV_TOTAL
    FROM
        EMPLOYEES
    WHERE
        ID = :NEW.ID;

    :NEW.TOTAL := LV_TOTAL;
END;
/
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3689f154f3574d8d16156d819cb7bb47)

Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

If there is always a one-to-one correspondence between the rows of the `bonus` table and the `employees` table then the better solution would be to push back that the requirements are wrong and the `bonus` table should be rolled into the `employee` table and the `total` column could be a `VIRTUAL` column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employees (
  id     NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  salary NUMBER,
  bonus  NUMBER,
  total  NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( salary + COALESCE( bonus, 0 ) )
);

INSERT INTO employees ( id, salary, bonus )
  SELECT 1, 100, 10   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 100, NULL FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM employees;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ID | SALARY | BONUS | TOTAL
> -: | -----: | ----: | ----:
>  1 |    100 |    10 |   110
>  2 |    100 |  null |   100
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b1d5bd4868bb86d2d589c284a61f042a)*

Comment: Your answer was very helpful! 
But I can't change the structures. So, I used triggers instead.
I highly appreciate your effort! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this easily with a view:

```sql
CREATE VIEW EMPLOYEE_CALC_TOTAL AS
SELECT e.id, e.salary + b.increase as total
  FROM employees e
  JOIN bonus b ON b.id = e.id
```

This would stay up to date automatically.
However if employee to bonus isn't always a 1 to 1 relationship you'd get duplicate rows for each extra bonus row.

Comment: Thanks! but that doesn't update the bonus table. I need it to be updated.

Comment: You can create a trigger when insert and update to get these values and update your total column