# create new column with conditional values from existing column in MySql workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

i have a column in my MySql table named "details" like this:

[image: like this]

now i want to add another column named "name" which will contain only the first word of each cell of column "details", like this:

[image]

so far i have done this:

```
select 
    substring(details, 1, instr(details, ' ')) 
from 
    my_table
```

now how to add this to a column "name"?

Comment: use computed column https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222044/column-calculated-from-another-column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to extract the first word of each value. For example:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('Wellcare Value (HMO-POS)', ' ', 1) AS name
```

Output:

```
Wellcare
```

To add this to your table, you have a couple of options. If you are running MySQL 5.7.6 or later, you can use a generated column as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222044/column-calculated-from-another-column) and the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN name VARCHAR(50) AS (SUBSTRING_INDEX(details, ' ', 1))
```

If you want to save storage at the expense of fetch time, declare the column as `VIRTUAL`, otherwise declare it as `STORED`.

You can also create a [`VIEW`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html) which includes this expression as a column. This is similar to a `VIRTUAL` generated column but will also work on versions of MySQL which don't support generated columns:

```
CREATE VIEW mytable_view AS
SELECT *, SUBSTRING_INDEX(details, ' ', 1) AS name
FROM mytable
```

The final option would be to create an actual column and then update it via a trigger, but both the preceding options are preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
select 
    substring(details, 1, instr(details, ' '))  As Name
from 
    my_table
```

Answer (score 1):

use `position()` function

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=84371f4f4b77f4c633a1fbc9ec446138)**

```
select 
    substring(details, 1, POSITION(' ' IN details)) 
from 
    my_table
```

OUTPUT:

```
value
Wellcare
```

ALSO `locate()` can be used

```
 select 
        substring(details, 1, LOCATE(' ', details)) 
    from 
        my_table
```