# What is the syntax error in this column addition statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb, mysql-5.7

I'd like to have a column that has a value dependant on other columns of the same table in MySQL Server 5.7 (InnoDB Cluster).

As a base for my statement, and as a test, I've used the following instruction:

```sql
ALTER TABLE contracts
ADD COLUMN curr_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

But I want my column to be a `DATE` and to have a value that is always a date resulting from the formula `ADDDATE(order_loaded_on, INTERVAL FLOOR(delivery_time * 1.4) DAY)` (where `order_loaded_on` is a `DATE` and `delivery_time` is an `INT`), so I wrote and ran the following:

```sql
ALTER TABLE contracts
ADD COLUMN est_delivery_on DATE
DEFAULT ADDDATE(order_loaded_on, INTERVAL FLOOR(delivery_time * 1.4) DAY)
ON UPDATE ADDDATE(order_loaded_on, INTERVAL FLOOR(delivery_time * 1.4) DAY)
```

But it returns a syntax error near to `ADDDATE(order_loaded_on, INTERVAL FLOOR(delivery_time * 1.4) DAY)` on line 4, so I ran it without the `ON UPDATE` clause and it works. The problem is that without the latter clause it doesn't update when the record changes.

Where am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

As per suggestion, I've tried to add it as a generated column running the following:

```sql
ALTER TABLE CrmContratto ADD COLUMN PrevistaConsegna DATE AS ADDDATE(DataCaricamentoOrdine, INTERVAL FLOOR(TempiConsegna * 1.4) DAY)
```

But it returns another syntax error.

The correct statement is in the accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: I think a calculated column will be better than a default here. Look at this other post for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5222044/2557263

Comment: @Alejandro Thanks for your comment. I didn't think about calculated columns and I agree that it would be better.
I've tried to run `ALTER TABLE CrmContratto ADD COLUMN PrevistaConsegna DATE AS ADDDATE(DataCaricamentoOrdine, INTERVAL FLOOR(TempiConsegna * 1.4) DAY)` but it returns another syntax error.

Comment: Update the question with this new attempt and the exact error message you've got. Also include the exact server version you're using.

Comment: The column of DATE datatype may have only literal, not expressional, DEFAULT and ON UPDATE values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a function in `ON UPDATE`.

But you can use a generated column, which does the same as it gets generates its values when you insert or update the row

```
ALTER TABLE contracts
ADD COLUMN est_delivery_on DATE
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (order_loaded_on + INTERVAL FLOOR(delivery_time * 1.4) DAY) STORED
```